# What are some good data cleanup tools?

Tags: csv, data-visualization, etl, data-cleaning

I am parsing large amounts of complex files (mostly CSV files but some are not) and I need to structure/parse them into some standard formats. This not only involves row wise cleanup of data but some simple individual cell-based logic. I want a tool that a non-programmer can use also so a business team member can write simple drag and drop logic and not take up engineering time. So far, I have looked at [Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) and [Data wrangler](http://vis.stanford.edu/wrangler/) and the last one looks great. Are there any other such tools out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ETL tools are oriented more towards relational databases, but also have support for XML and CSV file input/output. Examples:

- http://www.talendforge.org/
- http://kettle.pentaho.com/

Could easily be too complicated for your requirements though. Also, see this similar question on SO (with additional links): [What software is availible for data quality checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445403/what-software-is-availible-for-data-quality-checking) .

Comment: Another ETL tool with data cleansing abilities mentioned usually with the two above is [CloverETL](http://www.cloveretl.com)